# Is ASP.NET web forms object oriented?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We are currently in a tough spot in our university project group. This semester is about object oriented programming. We are to build a web application using ASP.NET. Months ago we decided to use webforms instead of MVC. At the moment we are having some doubts as to if webforms are object oriented. All the content pages have a class but this is the only classes that we have. So my question basically is: Is webforms object oriented and why?

Comment: The pages aren't the only classes you'd be dealing with. The individual controls are also classes (such as a Button or a GridView). And many of those controls can be bound to objects. Why did you pick Web Forms (a dead framework) to base your project around rather than a much more modern and user friendly framework like ASP.NET Core MVC?

Answer (score 1):

On Microsofts website, 'The ASP.NET page framework presents an object model that enables you to think of your forms as a unit, not as separate client and server pieces. In this model, you can program the page in a more intuitive way than in traditional Web applications, including the ability to set properties for page elements and respond to events.'

So yes, ASP.NET now implements object oriented programming, I believe that in the beginning, not all web application models implementing, but at least now they do, so mvc or webforms will have object oriented features to it. The models are objects themselves, it is possible that mvc would have more features that are oop, but webforms implements models also.

On a Microsoft tutorial they also state that to learn webforms an understanding of object-oriented programming, web-development(html, css, javascript), relational databases, and n-tier architecture are necessary to begin. Here is a link and at the bottom it compares asp.net mvc to webforms https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/what-is-web-forms